What and who does Squealer represent in Animal Farm?
What and who does the pig named Squealer in the novella Animal Farm represent in both history and modern society?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Please focus on a single thing that Squealer could represent. It currently seems that you want two separate answers, one for history and one for modern society. Squealer likely represents at most one specific thing.
